# PHP check if not empty and the value of another GET

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

I have a POS and need to check 2 things before I save a sale in MySQL

Code to get and check the information I need

```
$invoice=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['same_invoice']);
$customer=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['same_customer']);
```

If invoice is empty the customer is also empty because is the first prodyct in this invoice so we assign a invoice number and we ask the customer to show identification, the invoice is generated automatic so we input the ID-number of the customer and save to MySQL

Now the problem

If the customer wants to buy 2 products we dont need to give the order a new invoice number neither the ID but we must check both in MySQL

code I am trying but not working

```
if( $invoice is empty && $customer is also empty)
{ we create new invoice an ask customer for id first time }
if( $invoice is empty && $customer is NOT empty)
{ we create new invoice but do not ask customer for id }
else
{ we use the $invoice and $customer comming from the form }
```

Any idea how to check that?

Comment: What you posted as "*code I am trying*" is not actual code, so we cannot give you feedback on why it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe use what u created...

Comment: thanks, have a good day you too

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that the `$_POST` values are actually set, first. I would guess that is where your error is coming from.

```
$invoice = (isset($POST['same_invoice']) ? $_POST['same_invoice'] : null;
$customer = (isset($POST['same_customer']) ? $_POST['customer'] : null;

if(empty($customer) || empty($invoice)) {
  //Use values from form
} else {
  //Create new invoice
}
```

Comment: ZAC, how about this (gives me error)

 if ($_GET['document'] =="A") && (empty($customer); { ... How to build this checking if document is equal to and if empty or not the $customer?

Comment: I can totally help with that, but you should ask another question since this is a different problem. :) Comment the link to your next one, and I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

```
 $invoice=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['same_invoice']);
    $customer=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['same_customer']);
    if(!empty($invoice)&&!empty($invoice)){
    //do whatever you want to do with it.
}
```

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means
>   empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var
>   == false.